# Firebase api key restriction allow chrome extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a website which uses Firebase authentication and realtime database. I've restricted Firebase API Key access to my server only (HTTP referrers - 'https://projectname.firebaseapp.com/'). But now I also want to allow my chrome extension to access it.

Answer (score 8):

Found a solution -

Adding this to HTTP referrers worked - 'chrome-extension://yourextensionid/'.

Any better or more secure solution is welcomed!

Comment: This is the correct way to secure an API key in an extension. There is soo much bad advice how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

⚠️ Spoiler Bad News: **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header cannot help as a security measure with Chrome Extensions.

What you can do is create a custom authentication system ([JWT](https://jwt.io/) or anything that you can store with the [storage api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) for instance). Otherwise you can send an [error code](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) (unauthorised or unavailable). This can happen totally in the background. You can setup this handshake and store the key. You just have to make sure that this kind of auth requires that it comes from the browser and be able to verify the signature to make sure your token is not used elsewhere (like with curl or another server). [JWT](https://jwt.io/) might be the best solution here imho.

GLHF!