# Restrict google maps api key in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-extension

In order to call google maps api (places) I need to embed the api key in the extension itself. Although google does offer restrictions to be placed on the api key I don't know what I can leverage for a chrome extension.
[API Key Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices)

Comment: An extension is stored on a client browser and everything there can be investigated by a user who knows how to use devtools so there's no secure method to include the key with the source code. You'll have to create a separate remote service to which your extension connects/authorizes.

Comment: This will work for API keys as well as Firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53976190/firebase-api-key-restriction-allow-chrome-extension#53976215

Comment: But someone can spoof referrer header. So this might not be secure.